# Can't access Terminal anymore, only shows a cursor

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal, path

I run OS X.

Following these directions ([Installing MySQL on Mac OS X](http://techxplorer.com/2011/03/03/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x/)) I added a file to `/usr` and the contents were

```
PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

Actually I was trying to get the `mysql` command to work now I cannot access terminal. All I get is a cursor but no command line. I also cannot find the file I created in the Finder. I used command shift G to find the folder `/usr` and the file is not there.

Comment: You could try installing another terminal emulator and try to fix the situation through it.

Comment: Note that you can open the Terminal preferences and under _Startup_ tab, you can set _Shell open with_ to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: I tried Harrold's suggestion and it did nothing. You might be right that this is not what caused the problem. Around this time I was also logging into mysql directly through its path in /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

Comment: .profile perhaps? I was following these directions   http://techxplorer.com/2011/03/03/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x/  Step 6

Comment: Please **answer your own question** as soon as you can (i.e. in a couple of hours). There's a button below for that. Don't put the solution into the question. Thanks for sticking around!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved the problem by restarting my computer. I am really not sure what the problem was.

I got the idea because `Could not open a new pseudo-tty.` appeared in my terminal after following slhck directions to remove my .profile file. then i searched google and found this; 
http://blogs.oreilly.com/digitalmedia/2008/03/fixing-terminal-tty-errors.html.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

#### Why is your `bash` not starting up?

If your `bash` is not starting up correctly, one of its configuration files is borked. These are:

- `/etc/profile`

And after that, the first one of these it can find:

- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `~/.profile`

If you followed that tutorial correctly, you created the `~/.profile` file. But not in `/usr`. It should reside in your `$HOME` directory, which is at `/Users/your-username`, and known as `~` to the shell. You can put anything you want into `/usr` and it wouldn't affect bash starting.

#### Let's remove `~/.profile`

Try to go into Terminal.app settings and changing the following:

[image]

The command you want to execute is:

> `/bin/rm /Users/your-username/.profile`

Don't forget to untick *Run inside shell*. Of course, change `your-username` to your *actual* short user name. Once you open that Terminal profile, your existing `.profile` file will be deleted.

You can then uncheck the *Run command* field and try to start over.

#### Other means of debugging

If the above didn't help, from the same *Run command* field, try running:

> `/usr/bin/tail -n 10 /Users/your-username/.bash_history`

This will trace back your last steps, which would be valuable information to add to your post.

#### Your Terminal shows `Could not open a new pseudo-tty`?

In that case, a reboot is needed. Somehow you created too many forks, exceeding the file system limits. This should be restored by simply rebooting your Mac.

Comment: Here is my history

/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
cd /usr/local/mysql
ls
ls
ls
ls
ls
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
cd ~
vi .profile

However I restarted and the problem went away. Apparently it helps.

Comment: How far did you get with `vi`? Were you able to save and quit? Well, anyway, if your problem is solved …

Comment: I was able to save and quit.